# Request.GetOwinContext().Get<T> return null in APIControler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, token, asp.net-apicontroller

I Could not retrieve the data from OwinContext Environment that I store it after authenticate by token.

this is the Code:
[ValidateClientAuthentication]
In thins Code I validate the ClientID of the User and then store the data of ApplicationClient in OwinContext in this line

```
public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        ...
        ApplicationClient App = new ApplicationClient();
        App.Id = clientId;
        App.ClientSecretHash = clientSecret;
        // Storing Client Data
        context.OwinContext.Set<ApplicationClient>("oauth:client", App);
        context.Validated(clientId);
    }
```

[GrantResourceOwnerCredentials]
Here I Validate User Credentials and Add Climes to the Token

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ...
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
    {          
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
        context.Validated(identity);
    }
    else
    {
        context.SetError("Login Field", "Error username or password");
    }
}
```

[ControlerCode] Now Here is My Problem

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectedMenu> GetAllMenus() // Resturants ID
    {
        // client is Null
        ApplicationClient client = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationClient>("oauth:client");
    }
}
```

Comment: `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` is called only when the user requests a new token. Are you trying to share your `ApplicationClient` between different requests? This is not possible at all without some sort of persisted session. I strongly advice you to avoid this approach and store those information inside the token using Claims.

Comment: Also, can you clarify *why* you need both clientId and clientSecret inside your controller? What's the purpose of the clientSecret once the client is validated inside the Owin OAuth pipeline?

Comment: Hi @FedericoDipuma thanks for the replay .. you are right I need just to share the client_id with my APIs .. I will remove the secret code. but I need the client ID to retrieve some client information in server side before run the API.  few seconds ago I just added the application client to the claim by using JavaScriptSerializer then  Deserialize it at the API Controller and its work fine. but the token now it to long :). so is there a better way to do that.

Comment: How long is the clientId? I do not think you need to serialize it, it usually is only a small string.

Comment: Not just the ID there is about 5 properties in that class ApplicationClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really only add the `clientId` inside your token, so you may retrieve it anytime after the login process.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    // ...
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
    {          
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("oauth-client", context.ClientId));
        context.Validated(identity);
    }
    else
    {
        context.SetError("Login Field", "Error username or password");
    }
}
```

You may also create an extension method to help you in retrieving the `clientId`:

```
public static class PrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string GetClientId(this IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return (principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?
            .Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "oauth-client")?
            .Value;
    }    
}
```

And inside your controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectedMenu> GetAllMenus() // Resturants ID
    {
        var clientId = User.GetClientId();
    }
}
```

Regarding the token size: if your `clientId` string is too long I suggest you to use another one and store any other client information (including a longer id if is needed) inside the database. The client identifier should be a small and unique string easy to transmit.

Comment: about the length of the token is about 500 char